# How can I commit changes to GitHub from within a R script?

Tags: r, git, shell, github, rstudio

I am trying to automate some basic git operations from within a R script. I am using Rstudio on Windows OS. This may be helpful for example if you wished to update GitHub when a script finishes performing some automated task.

I wrote some simple functions that utilize R's `shell()` function and the Window's `&` pipe operator to send a chain of commands to the OS terminal:

```
# Git status.
gitstatus <- function(dir = getwd()){
  cmd_list <- list(
    cmd1 = tolower(substr(dir,1,2)),
    cmd2 = paste("cd",dir),
    cmd3 = "git status"
  )
  cmd <- paste(unlist(cmd_list),collapse = " & ")
  shell(cmd)
}

# Git add.
gitadd <- function(dir = getwd()){
  cmd_list <- list(
    cmd1 = tolower(substr(dir,1,2)),
    cmd2 = paste("cd",dir),
    cmd3 = "git add --all"
  )
  cmd <- paste(unlist(cmd_list),collapse = " & ")
  shell(cmd)
}

# Git commit.
gitcommit <- function(msg = "commit from Rstudio", dir = getwd()){
  cmd_list <- list(
    cmd1 = tolower(substr(dir,1,2)),
    cmd2 = paste("cd",dir),
    cmd3 = paste0("git commit -am ","'",msg,"'")
  )
  cmd <- paste(unlist(cmd_list),collapse = " & ")
  shell(cmd)
}

# Git push.
gitpush <- function(dir = getwd()){
  cmd_list <- list(
    cmd1 = tolower(substr(dir,1,2)),
    cmd2 = paste("cd",dir),
    cmd3 = "git push"
  )
  cmd <- paste(unlist(cmd_list),collapse = " & ")
  shell(cmd)
}
```

My `gitstatus`, `gitadd`, and `gitpush` functions work. The `gitcommit` function does not work. It generates the following error:

> fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
>   Warning message:
>   In shell(cmd) : 'd: & cd D:/Documents/R/my_path & git commit -am 'commit from Rstudio'' execution failed with error code 128

The `gitpush` function works because if you switch to the terminal or git within Rstudio, you can commit changes and then successfully call `gitpush`.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

...

**Note:** I have Git bash installed, and I can successfully use git from the Windows command terminal and Rstudio. I also tried an alternative strategy which was to have R write a temporary `.bat` file and then execute this, but this strategy also gets hung up on the commit step.

Comment: Several packages on CRAN (!!) directly interface the git API so that you don't need shell -- [git2r](https://cran.r-project.org/package=git2r) is one.  My [drat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=drat) package can use either it or a `system()` command if the command-line program `git` is available.  You can check the source of the (fairly simple) functions [at the git source repo of drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

The answer lie within  [Dirk Eddelbuettel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) **drat** package function [addrepo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat/blob/master/R/addRepo.R). It was also necessary to use [git2r's](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/git2r/index.html) `config` function to insure that git recognizes R. git2r's functions probably provide a more robust solution for working with git from an R script in the future. In the meantime, here's how I fixed the problem.

- Install git2r. Use git2r::config() to insure git recognizes R.
- From Dirk's code I modified the `gitcommit()` function to utilize `sprintf()` and `system()` to execute a system command:

```
# Git commit.
gitcommit <- function(msg = "commit from Rstudio", dir = getwd()){
  cmd = sprintf("git commit -m\"%s\"",msg)
  system(cmd)
}
```

Sprintf's output looks like this:

```
[1] "git commit -m\"commit from Rstudio\""
```

#### Example

```
#install.packages("git2r")
library(git2r)

# Insure you have navigated to a directory with a git repo.
dir <- "mypath"
setwd(dir)

# Configure git.
git2r::config(user.name = "myusername",user.email = "myemail")

# Check git status.
gitstatus()

# Download a file.
url <- "https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/002/232/bullet_cat.jpg"
destfile <- "bullet_cat.jpg"
download.file(url,destfile)

# Add and commit changes. 
gitadd()
gitcommit()

# Push changes to github.
gitpush()
```

Well, the pic looks wonky, but I think you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read in [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334994/which-one-is-better-using-or-to-execute-multiple-commands-in-one-line), you should be using `&&`, not `&`, to separate multiple commands in the Git bash.  Try doing that:

```
gitcommit <- function(msg = "commit from Rstudio", dir = getwd()) {
    cmd_list <- list(
        cmd1 = tolower(substr(dir, 1, 2)),
        cmd2 = paste("cd", dir),
        cmd3 = paste0("git commit -am ", "'", msg, "'")
    )
    cmd <- paste(unlist(cmd_list),collapse = " && ")
    shell(cmd)
}
```

Note that your `gitcommit` function will output something like this:

```
/v & cd /var/www/service/usercode/255741827 & git commit -am 'first commit'"
```

I don't know what purpose the `substr(dir, 1, 2)` portion serves, but if my suggestion still doesn't work, then try removing it to leave just the `cd` and `git commit` commands.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. I tried && and that doesn't seem to fix things. The substr line is to insure that Windows changes the directory properly. For example, if you are in your D: drive and you need to change to the C: drive you need to enter c: in the terminal. Typing cd C:\my_path wont get you anywhere. You need to switch to the D: drive first with d:.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the syntax and simplicity of the [`gert`](https://docs.ropensci.org/gert/) package from rOpenSci. Specifically, to commit a repo you would do:

```
git_add("test.txt")
git_commit("Adding a file", author = "jerry <jerry@gmail.com>")
```

Top push to remote:

```
git_push(remote = "origin", repo = ".")
```

And see all other useful functions with this simple syntax.